# iOS Simulator でiAdのdidFailToReceiveAdWithError をテストしたい

Tags: swift, iad, ios-simulator

iAdのデリゲートメソッドである下記のメソッドをシミュレーターでテストしたい。
たまに、下記のメソッドが呼ばれるようなのだが、
条件がわからない。
集中してこのメソッドをデバッグしたいので、操作方法等があれば教えていください。

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    myAd.hidden = true
    myBannerAnime()
}
```